# How repeat index in pandas pivot table such that nan fill record-less rows?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Pardon my poorly phrased question--I'm not sure how to word it.

Given this pandas pivot table,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('AABB'),
                   'col2': list('acab'),
                   'values': [1,3,4,5]})
pt = pd.pivot_table(df,
                    index=['col1', 'col2'],
                    values='values',
                    aggfunc=sum)
```

Output:

```
col1  col2
A     a       1
      c       3
B     a       4
      b       5
```

How can I make the pivot table output this instead:

```
col1  col2
A     a        1
      b      NaN
      c        3
B     a        4
      b        5
      c      NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert your column to the `category` data type (new in pandas 0.15!) you will get the aggregation that you are after:

```
df.col2 = df.col2.astype('category')
In [378]: df.groupby(['col1','col2']).sum()
Out[378]:
           values
col1 col2
A    a          1
     b        NaN
     c          3
B    a          4
     b          5
     c        NaN
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks. I had no idea something as simple as this would do the trick. I noticed that either a groupby or a pivot_table would work. Do you know if there's an advantage to using one over another?

Comment: i usually use groupby since i come from a sql background and it makes more sense to me (i can never remember how pivot works) however i'd encourage you to use both and see which one you're more comfortable with